# From Page_Load to One_Method and from One_Method to Another_Method

Tags: c#, asp.net, ado.net

Hey I make one more question with my full code because I am really stuck in this point.
When page loads a panel is filled with Book Categories taken from a database. This Categories are linkbuttons too. When I click one category a table is created below with all books on that category.
In that table the first cell is filled with Book's Title that is Linkbutton too.
I just want when I click i that Book'S Title linkbutton to fire the book_Details functions
so that the page now will show only the book I chose.

Instead of that whenever I click books'title linkbutton page loads again from 0.

The markup is:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
<div style="position: relative; top: 5%; left: 5%;">
    <asp:Panel ID="MyPanel" runat="server"></asp:Panel>
</div>
<asp:MultiView ID="MultiView2" runat="server">
    <asp:View ID="View1" runat="server">
        <div style="overflow: auto; height: 400px;">
            <asp:Table ID="ProductTBL" runat="server" BorderColor="Black" BorderStyle="Double" CellPadding="5" CellSpacing="5" BorderWidth="1px">
            </asp:Table>
        </div>
    </asp:View>
    <asp:View ID="View2" runat="server">
        <asp:Table ID="detail_TBL" runat="server" BorderColor="Black" BorderStyle="Double" CellPadding="5" CellSpacing="5" BorderWidth="1px"></asp:Table>
    </asp:View>
</asp:MultiView>
</asp:Content>
```

And the code-behind is:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String conString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source =" +
                Server.MapPath("~/e-bookstoredb.accdb");
    using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(conString))
    {
        connection.Open();

        ыtring query = "SELECT * FROM category";
        using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, connection))
        {
            OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                string literal = (string)reader["Name"];

                LinkButton lnk_button = new LinkButton();
                lnk_button.Text = literal;
                lnk_button.ID = "cat_B" + reader["ID"].ToString();
                lnk_button.CommandArgument = reader["ID"].ToString();
                lnk_button.CommandName = reader["ID"].ToString();
                lnk_button.Command += new CommandEventHandler(books_Show);

                MyPanel.Controls.Add(lnk_button);
                MyPanel.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</br>"));
            }
            reader.Close();
        }
        connection.Close();
    }
}

protected void books_Show(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LinkButton lnk = sender as LinkButton;
    string cat = lnk.CommandArgument;
    MultiView2.ActiveViewIndex = 0;

    string ConStr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source =" + Server.MapPath("~/e-bookstoredb.accdb");
    using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(ConStr))
    {
        con.Open();
        string query = "SELECT * FROM product WHERE category = @cat";
        using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, con))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cat", cat);
            OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            TableCell cell;

            TableRow row = new TableRow();
            TableCell titleCell = new TableCell();
            titleCell.Text = "Τίτλος";

            TableCell desCell = new TableCell();
            desCell.Text = "Περιγραφή";
            TableCell priceCell = new TableCell();
            priceCell.Text = "Τιμή";

            row.Cells.Add(titleCell);
            row.Cells.Add(desCell);
            row.Cells.Add(priceCell);

            ProductTBL.Rows.Add(row);
            LinkButton book_button;

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                book_button = new LinkButton();
                book_button.ID = "book" + reader["ID"].ToString();
                book_button.Text = (string)reader["Title"];
                book_button.CommandArgument = (string) reader["Title"];
                book_button.CommandName = "cmd" + reader["ID"].ToString();
                book_button.Command += new CommandEventHandler(book_Details);

                row = new TableRow();

                cell = new TableCell();
                cell.Controls.Add(book_button);
                row.Cells.Add(cell);

                cell = new TableCell();
                cell.Text = (string)reader["Description"];
                row.Cells.Add(cell);

                cell = new TableCell();
                cell.Text = reader["price"].ToString()+"€";
                row.Cells.Add(cell);

                ProductTBL.Rows.Add(row);
            }
            reader.Close();
        }
        con.Close();
    }
}

protected void book_Details(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MultiView2.ActiveViewIndex = 1;
    LinkButton lnk = sender as LinkButton;
    String bookTitle = lnk.CommandArgument;
    //...And then I just create a table to show only the book user selected 
    //...this table gets filled buy this query = " SELECT * FROM product WHERE Title=@bookTitle   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You must wrap your code within `Page_Load` with `if(!IsPostBack)` as shown below. This is because according to ASP.Net page lifecycle Page_Load fires first and control events firs after that.

So, whenever you click your `LinkButtons` the server first calls the Page_Load and then it calls `LinkButton`'s click event.

So, it's a good idea to wrap your `Page_Load` code where you only wants to execute once during `Page_Load` like this.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        // Your Page_Load logic goes here
    }
}
```

According to MSDN the definition for `IsPostBack` is

> Gets a value that indicates whether the page is being rendered for the
> first time or is being loaded in response to a postback.
>
> **true** if the page is being loaded in response to a client postback;
> otherwise, **false**.

Hope this helped!

Comment: Thanks very much man! But when the second method (book_details) is fired I want to pass the right Argument to show the right book. How to take that argument in page_load method. Like I do in books_show method?

Comment: Why do you need it in Page_Load event? Give me a detailed explanation regarding what you need now

Comment: I could say for example in page_load
if(Session["method"] == "showbookdetails")
{ 
   book_detail(sender, e);
} 
but how can I take the argument with me?

Comment: in that way the book_Details method is fired normaly. But when I try to take the argument in a string : 
LinkButton lnk = sender as LinkButton;
String bookTitle = lnk.CommandArgument;

I get: NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code

Comment: Debug your books_Show event and see whether reader["Title"] gets a value for each row.

Comment: And, you can also try String bookTitle = lnk.Text; instead of String bookTitle = lnk.CommandArgument; in your book_Details event.

Comment: It gets a value normaly when books_show method is fired.
Maybe you have skype to show you the code more easily?
my name is kostistank

Comment: I'm at work so can't skype. Did you try  String bookTitle = lnk.Text; instead of String bookTitle = lnk.CommandArgument; in your book_Details event

Comment: I cant understand. How I can get from Page_Load to books_Show normaly and take the category argument with me but I cant get from books_Show to book_details.

Comment: In your bookTitle link do you see the book title? If so, why can't you use the LinkButton.Text as I suggested?

Comment: try String bookTitle = lnk.Text; instead of String bookTitle = lnk.CommandArgument; in your book_Details event

Comment: same exception is thrown. NullReferenceException. Mayby everytime one linkbutton is hitted page refreshes and looses the CommandArguments